Getting a bad SQL grammar error for a named parameter - removing the parameter eliminates the error
I have looked one by one at all of the other questions, and I am not overcoming my issue.  I have vastly simplified the code, and I have what I believe is a novel demonstration of the issue.
This code works:
@Repository
public class MyFriend {
    @Autowired  
    private NamedParameterJdbcTemplate namedParameterJdbcTemplate;
    public List<TransmitUnit> getTransmissionList(LocalDate workingDate)
    {
        List<TransmitUnit> retValue = null;     
        String sql = "SELECT working_day as workingDate, origin_code as originCode FROM core.sort_transmission WHERE working_day = '2024-08-23'";
        MapSqlParameterSource namedParameters = new MapSqlParameterSource();
        namedParameters.addValue("working_day", workingDate.toString());
        retValue = namedParameterJdbcTemplate.query(sql, namedParameters, new BeanPropertyRowMapper<>(TransmitUnit.class));
        for (TransmitUnit u: retValue) {
            LOGGER.info("Got this tu {}", u.getWorkingDate());
        }
        return retValue;
    }

If I replace the '2024-08-23' in sql with a named parameter:
String sql = "SELECT working_day as workingDate, origin_code as originCode 
FROM core.sort_transmission WHERE working_day = :working_day";

Now, I get an error in the statement:
ERRO class="MyFriend" method="getTransmissionList" transactionId="6913d8d6-d56a-4c8f-bd78-32c976817d39-1724878713995" 
request="[2024-08-28]" errorType="org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException" errorMsg="PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar 
[SELECT working_day as workingDate, origin_code as originCode 
FROM core.sort_transmission WHERE working_day = ?]" errorOrigin="org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLStateSQLExceptionTranslator.doTranslate(SQLStateSQLExceptionTranslator.java:104)"

I am wondering why the SQL shows a ? as if this was a generic prepared statement instead of with a named parameter.  I know this has worked before, I am not sure what I could be doing wrong.
EDIT: Based on John Bollinger's comment I submitted an answer that I think nicely illustrates the exact type problem and would be enlightening for future viewers.

Mostly because it works everywhere. Named parameters are vendor specific in JDBC.

I don't think it's significant that the error message represents the parameter as ? instead of with the assigned name.  It's just how that driver converts it to text for display.

@lopass please also add TransmitUnit in the question

Is it possible that the problem is the data type of the parameter value you're putting in the ParameterSource? If the SQL data type of the column in question is DATE, for example, then it might make a difference that you are providing a string.  Including that it might make a difference whether you use a query with a literal or a parameterized query.

@JohnBollinger this might be the issue, removing the toString() in the named parameter add makes the code fail to return anything, but there is no longer a bad grammar error.  Trying to coax it into returning something.

JDBC only has positional parameters, and those are represented by ?, Spring does the mapping from named to positional parameters for you. You're focusing on the wrong thing. In any case, you need to post the full exception stacktrace, not just some error summary.

John Bollinger was correct.  The type in Java needs to match the type in SQL.    Removing the toString() worked.
Final working code:
@Repository
public class MyFriend {
    @Autowired  
    private NamedParameterJdbcTemplate namedParameterJdbcTemplate;
    public List<TransmitUnit> getTransmissionList(LocalDate workingDate)
    {
        List<TransmitUnit> retValue = null;     
        String sql = "SELECT working_day as workingDate, origin_code as originCode FROM core.sort_transmission WHERE working_day = :working_day";
        MapSqlParameterSource namedParameters = new MapSqlParameterSource();
        namedParameters.addValue("working_day", workingDate);
        retValue = namedParameterJdbcTemplate.query(sql, namedParameters, new BeanPropertyRowMapper<>(TransmitUnit.class));
        for (TransmitUnit u: retValue) {
            LOGGER.info("Got this tu {}", u.getWorkingDate());
        }
        return retValue;
    }


Weird. That shouldn't matter, as JDBC defines a conversion from string to DATE. Which database are you using?

postgres in an AWS RDS instance


Truncate the DB date type to only consider the date part.

Pass the localDate from java as a specific string format, then convert in SQL query to date.


String sql = "SELECT working_day as workingDate, origin_code as originCode FROM core.sort_transmission WHERE trunc(working_day) = ':working_day'";

MapSqlParameterSource namedParameters = new MapSqlParameterSource();

namedParameters.addValue("working_day", workingDate.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy"));

